# Appendix in book - chapter, not part

Tags: appendices, book-design

I'm wondering whether is possible to have Appendix designed as a chapter with sections in book document class and not as a part with chapters.

This is what I get using appendix package

```
\documentclass[onesided]{book}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Appendices}
\section{A1 First appendix}
\section{A2 Second appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would like to get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never, ever type chapter/section numbers manually!**

If you have read the [`appendix` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf), you would know that `\appendixpage` will create a “part-like” page. So, don’t use it.

Since you are using the standard class: `book`, there aren’t many hooks we can use. So I proposed the following:

1. `\suppresschapternumber` makes the numbered chapter to be typeset as an unnumbered chapter, and it changes how the rest of the chapters are written into the ToC.
2. `\removedotbetweenchapterandsection`, well, removes the dot between the chapter letter and the section number.

**Use the following with extreme caution!**

```
\documentclass[onesided]{book}

%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\suppresschapternumber{%
  \let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}}
    {}
    {}{}%
}
\newcommand*\removedotbetweenchapterandsection{%
  \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter\@arabic\c@section}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\appendix

\suppresschapternumber
\removedotbetweenchapterandsection

\chapter{Appendices}
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}

\chapter{More appendices}
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}

\end{document}
```

---

[image: ToC]

---

[image: Appendices]

---

[image: More appendices]

Comment: O noticed now one thing - there is bad header in appendices - Appendix A - Appendices instead of desired Appendices. Is it also possible to change it?

Comment: Moreover, when you use hyperref package, this will add letter in TOC before chapter name, e.g. A Appendices